# Source file not refreshing

Tags: visual-studio-2008, add-in

I am trying to create a Visual Studio  2008 add in, so I have created a Visual Studio Add in Project, pressed F5 to see it run an the icon for my new add in appears at the top of the Tools menu.

So after stopping the execution I made a few changes to the source code and pressed F5 again, no changes what so ever and no debugging because "No symbols have been loaded for this document"

It seams that visual studio is using the first dll that was created. How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solved.

I had changed my output dll name, but on the configuration file ".addin" if was still referring to the original name